# Why ORDER BY + MAX() return the maximum value when I grouping?

Tags: mysql

I have this part of a query :

```
GROUP BY trackid 
ORDER BY MAX(history.date) DESC
```

And I see that, when I grouping, it returns the row with maximum date for each group. Why this behaviour? Order should works on the whole rows...not on the grouping ?!?!?

**EDIT** (Example)

This is my whole query :

```
SELECT tracklist.value, history.date
FROM history JOIN tracklist ON history.trackid=tracklist.trackid 
ORDER BY history.date DESC
```

The result is :

```
tracklist3  2011-04-27 15:40:36
tracklist2  2011-04-27 13:15:43
tracklist2  2011-04-02 00:30:02
tracklist2  2011-04-01 14:20:12
tracklist1  2011-03-02 14:13:58
tracklist1  2011-03-01 12:11:50
```

As you can see, all line is correctly ordered by history.date.
Now I'd like to group them, keeping for each group the row with MAX history.date. 
So the output should be :

```
tracklist3  2011-04-27 15:40:36
tracklist2  2011-04-27 13:15:43
tracklist1  2011-03-02 14:13:58
```

I see that :

```
GROUP BY trackid 
ORDER BY MAX(history.date) DESC
```

works correctly, but I really don't understand why it works :) Order by is for the whole rows, not for the grouping....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say `SELECT trackid, MAX(history.date) ... GROUP BY trackid ORDER BY MAX(history.date) DESC` you are really saying: "Show me for each tracklist the most recent history entry and please show me the tracklist first whose most recent history entry is (overall) most recent."

The `ORDER BY` is applied **after** the grouping, (that's why it comes after the `GROUP BY` in the SQL).

Note that in your example, you have `SELECT tracklist.value, history.date` instead of `SELECT tracklist.value, MAX(history.date)`. That is just wrong and unfortunately MySQL does not give a warning but it choses a **random** `history.date` at its discretion.

Comment: Yeah, but I see that with my code, it return the trackid with MAXIMUM date, but ON GROUPING...and this is strange... isn't?

Comment: I don't understand. Please post the fields that you are SELECTing, the data you get and the data you'd expect.

Comment: So your code works and you want to know why and how? Updated my answer to a (hopefully) better explanation.

Comment: Yeah, you say correct : `The ORDER BY is applied after the grouping` ; but before order them, I need to get the row (for each group) with MAX date...Why this is done using ORDER BY MAX ? That's I really don't understand...

Comment: Oh, now I see. You forgot the MAX() in the SELECT fields.

Comment: That's another thing that I don't understand...and for the moment I hope to avoid this! What I don't understand at the moment is before :)

Comment: I think that is the key to your confusion. Updated answer again.

Comment: Uhm no man! :) Rest the fact that MySql group the rows in some manner; ORDER BY is executed later. I don't understand why ORDER BY MAX should group rows in other manner...

Comment: I don't understand anything... order by max(date) orders by date because max(date) is a date, what would you expect the order to be?

Comment: Oh...so it GROUP checking the MAX() in the SELECT. But it also works if there aren't aggregate function; in that case it group randomly?

Comment: Correct, regard the value of the non-aggregated column as completely random. There are ugly hacks to get some deterministic behaviour but we don't want to talk about that. ;)

Comment: Now is more clear! :) As last thing : if I group, I add aggregate function on select but I order without aggregate, I see it take other history.date as SELECTION : how is possible?

Comment: If you order by a field that you don't select, it is implicitly added to the select fields, so you run into the same problem with the random value. You can instruct MySQL to warn you in such a case by setting `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT("ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,",@@sql_mode)`. Unfortunately the implementation of this mode is buggy, so you cannot use it at all times.

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY MAX(history.date) DESC` is somewhat redundant if all you want to do is order the result set.  Ordering applies to the **result set**.

Consider the results if you remove the ORDER BY clause.  Without that, your query would only be grouping on the trackid column, so it wouldn't be valid--you would need to add an aggregate function to the date column or add the date column to the GROUP BY clause.  By adding the aggregate function to the ORDER BY clause, you are essentially telling the SQL engine that for each group of trackid, get the maximum date.  This seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not fully understand the GROUP BY statement. I would recommend looking up a tutorial on it.

But essentially, the GROUP BY statement combines a number of rows into one. The column names you GROUP BY determine how unique the new combined rows will be. SQL doesn't know how to handle all of the non-grouped columns since each new combined row will be pulling data from a number of rows that contain different values in these columns. That's why you use aggregate functions on the non-grouped columns in the SELECT statement. The aggregate function `MAX()` looks at all of the values in the `history.date` column for the rows that are being combined and returns only one of them.  Additionally, the ORDER BY clause can only use columns that are being selected, that's why ORDER BY also must contain aggregate functions.